# Android Studio and Drag and Drop layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using the new Android Studio and I am wondering if there is any drag and drop functionality to create a layout like in Visual Studio with C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. The layout editor in ADT is just not very good and there are no really good WSYWIG tools out there AFAIK. You can drag and drop components into the layout, but it hardly ever does what you expect and you'll need to fix the xml layout code in the end anyway. It's much better to think of it as a layout preview tool and resign yourself to hand writing the layouts.

I see it as a bit of a benefit that I was forced to learn layout xml early. It really helps you to understand how the layout views and view groups interact with one another. It also forces you to be aware of the whole layout tree, which helps reduce unnecessary complexity (more views = worse performance).